# Xamarin Forms: How Can I Change the FlyoutItem.Icon's Color When It Is Selected/Deselected?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app.xaml, app-shell

I am using Material Design Font Icons as my icon source for my project.  The trouble is, since it's a *font* it needs a different color when selected vs. when deselected (as shown - the deselected white ones have white icons, which isn't awesome).

[image: Deselected icons are the same color as the background]

How can I modify the `Style` to change the color of the icon like it does the text and background color?

```xml
<!-- redacted because it would've never worked -->
```

### Edit 1:

Consensus is that using the VSM isn't going to work because it doesn't derive from `VisualElement`.  I've gotten it to work using a `Trigger` - but I'm not happy with the implementation.  This works:

```xml
<Shell.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<Style TargetType="FlyoutItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger TargetType="FlyoutItem" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="Checked" />
            <Setter Property="FlyoutIcon" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIconFont"
                                        Glyph="{StaticResource InformationOutlineGlyph}"
                                        Color="White" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

    
<FlyoutItem Title="About" >
    <FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIconFont"
                            Glyph="{StaticResource InformationOutlineGlyph}"
                            Color="Green" />
    </FlyoutItem.Icon>

    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

... but as you can see, I have to set the entire `FontImageSource` value - which has the `Glyph` property - so I have to repeat this `Style` each time for each `FlyoutItem`.

How can I rewrite this `Style` to be reusable and only change the color, not the other properties?

Comment: Probably not supported. "Icon" is a property of [FlyoutItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flyoutitem?view=xamarin-forms). Based on [description in visual-state-manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager), "This visual state group is supported for all classes that derive from VisualElement", which not includes flyout items.

Comment: Yep, I agree.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: The `Material Design Font Icons` could do what you want with the `Triggers`. I would provide the code sample later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `Material Design Icons`.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="fgColor">#66169C</Color>
        <Color x:Key="bgColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
        <Color x:Key="OverDueItem">#FF1C07</Color>

        <OnPlatform x:Key="Material" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Material Design Icons" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf#Material Design Icons" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <Style x:Key="MaterialIcons" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource Material}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource fgColor}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Large" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For more details about the Material Design Icons, you could download from the GitHub. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/MaterialDesignIcons/App2

And then create the style to change the background color when you selected.

```
  <Style x:Key="FloutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Accent" />

                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Change the Label TextColor with the `Triggers`.

```
 <Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid x:Name="grid" Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           
            <Label Style="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xf001;">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference grid}, Path=BackgroundColor}"
                        TargetType="Label"
                        Value="Accent">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                FontAttributes="Italic"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference grid}, Path=BackgroundColor}"
                        TargetType="Label"
                        Value="Accent">
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Updated:**

Change:

```
<Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
```

To:

```
 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
```

The whold trigger of the shell itemtemplate.

```
 <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference grid}, Path=BackgroundColor}"
                        TargetType="Label"
                        Value="Accent">
                        <!--<Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />-->
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You're on the right track, but I need it to work with `FlyoutItem.Icon` background color.  `FlyoutItem` doesn't inherit from `VisualElement` like a `Label` - so you can't use VSM - you have to use triggers.   I can't figure out how to change JUST the background color.

Comment: I have updated the reply. If you just want to change the background color, change the code in trigger for the background color. I change the color to yellow for your reference.

Comment: Please see the latest edit to my question.

Comment: @ScottBaker I have checked you edit. But for the background color, the trigger only used once in datatemplate. Do not need to repeat this Style each time for each FlyoutItem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and solved it as follows

Create a custom flyout with an additional `IconGlyphProperty`

```
class FlyoutItemIconFont : FlyoutItem
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconGlyphProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconGlyphProperty), typeof(string), typeof(FlyoutItemIconFont), string.Empty);
    public string IconGlyph
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(IconGlyphProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconGlyphProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Create a FlyoutItemTemplate with two Lables and VisualStateManager

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="FlyoutItemIcon"
                FontFamily="MaterialDesignFont"       
                Text="{Binding IconGlyph}"
                TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference FlyoutItemLabel} ,Path=TextColor}"
                FontSize="30"
                Margin="5"/>
            <Label x:Name="FlyoutItemLabel"
                Grid.Column="1"        
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Replace the original FlyoutItem in AppShell.xaml with the custom FlyoutItem

```
<controls:FlyoutItemIconFont Title="About" IconGlyph="{StaticResource IconInfo}">
    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
</controls:FlyoutItemIconFont>

<controls:FlyoutItemIconFont Title="Browse" IconGlyph="{StaticResource IconListBulleted}">
    <ShellContent Route="ItemsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
</controls:FlyoutItemIconFont>
```

Add the BaseStyle to the customFlyouItem

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:String x:Key="IconInfo">&#xF02FD;</x:String>
        <x:String x:Key="IconListBulleted">&#xF0279;</x:String>
        ...
        <Style TargetType="controls:FlyoutItemIconFont" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

Here is the Result

[image: FlyoutItem with IconFont with different Colors for selected und deselected Item]