# Xamarin.Forms: How to set the Color of Icons in FlyoutItems in AppShell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am implementing a Xamarin.Forms app using AppShell and can't seem to figure out how to set the color of the selected / unselected icons in the Flyout menu. Here is the section of the appshell.xaml that I believe is controlling the behavior (I used various high contrast colors to show what settings are controlling what). (The complete code sample: https://github.com/wadebaird/ShellExample for more reference):

```
<Style x:Name="FlyoutItem" Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <!-- This is the color of the unselected text for the labels in the flyout-->
                            <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Magenta" />
                            <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="Cyan" />
                            <!-- This is the background color of the selected icon in the flyout -->
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <!-- This is the color of the selected text in the flyout -->
                            <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                            <!-- This is the background color of the selected icon in the flyout -->
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And here is the visuals from these settings. In this image, the "Entity at the top is the "selected" item. I would expect / want the icons to match the colors of the text but can't seem to find the setting.

[image]

Here is what I'm going for to show how "white" for the icons doesn't work:

[image]

I can manually set the color on the FontImageSource, but then it is always that color and doesn't match the selected / unselected:

```
<ShellContent Route="aboutPage" Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" >
    <ShellContent.Icon>
        <FontImageSource Size="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}" Color="Black" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.InfoCircle}" FontFamily="FA-Solid" />
    </ShellContent.Icon>
</ShellContent>
```

I tried various things such as this withing the "Common States"- "Normal"/"Selected" and couldn't get anything to work.:

```
<Setter Property="FontImageSource.Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource PrimaryUnselectedTextColorLight}, Dark={StaticResource PrimaryUnselectedTextColorDark}}" />
```

And on a side note (and this is probably a bug). It appears on iOS that when first opening the flyout nothing is "selected":

[image]

Where on Android, the proper item is selected:

[image]

I know this is a seperate item, and I'll log a bug if I can't find an existing issue/bug, but I figured I'd mention it as someone thgat knows the answer to my above probably is already aware of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Wendy Zang [replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246778/xamarin-forms-how-to-set-the-color-of-icons-in-flyoutitems-in-appshell#answer-71248254) with a partial solution (it solved the background color but not the foreground), it got me on the right track
and I was able to find the [answer to this posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400688/xamarin-forms-how-can-i-change-the-flyoutitem-icons-color-when-it-is-selected#answer-65538823), which utilized two labels instead of an image. (I also tried to use the Image that Wendy suggested above and an effect like the `IconTintColorEffect.TintColor` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860955/add-overlay-color-to-an-image-using-xamarin-forms#answer-71044030), but I couldn't get that to work quite right either as the sizing of the icon was a lot trickier with it being an image.)

I tried the solution with having the different types of derived classes with the IconGlyph property and I got it to work well, but I didn't like the cleanliness of it. I then thought of using an IValueConverter to fix the binding for the label class:

```
public class FlyoutGlyphConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (value is not BaseShellItem baseShellItem)
            throw new ArgumentException($"This converter may only be used on values of type {nameof(BaseShellItem)}.");

        if (baseShellItem.Icon is not FontImageSource fontImageSource)
            throw new ArgumentException($"This converter may only be used on values of type {nameof(BaseShellItem)}s with Icons of type {nameof(FontImageSource)}.");

        return fontImageSource.Glyph;
    }
}
```

And my xaml ended up being like so:

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="root:IShellIconFont">
        <Grid Margin="0" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <!-- This is the color of the unselected text for the labels in the flyout-->
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="#2196F3" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                                <!-- This is the background color of the selected icon in the flyout -->
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemIcon" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <!-- This is the color of the selected text in the flyout -->
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="#2196F3" />
                                <!-- This is the background color of the selected icon in the flyout -->
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemIcon" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="#2196F3" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="FlyoutItemIcon" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="FA-Solid" FontSize="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}"
                    Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource FlyoutGlyph}}" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference FlyoutItemLabel}, Path=TextColor}"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
            <Label x:Name="FlyoutItemLabel" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="{StaticResource FlyoutLabelFontSize}" 
                    FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HeightRequest="45" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
<FlyoutItem Route="root" Title="Entitys" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <root:ShellContentIconFont Route="mainPage" Title="Entity" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.BookOpen}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}" />
    <root:ShellContentIconFont Route="favoritesPage" Title="Favorites" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Star}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FavoritesPage}" />
    <root:TabIconFont Route="entitys" Title="Entitys" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Book}" >
        <ShellContent Route="entitysCalendar" Title="Calendar" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EntitysCalendarPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="entitysList" Title="List" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EntitysListPage}" />
    </root:TabIconFont>
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Route="root" Title="Entitys" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Route="mainPage" Title="Entity" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Size="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.BookOpen}" FontFamily="FA-Solid" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
    <ShellContent Route="favoritesPage" Title="Favorites" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FavoritesPage}">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Size="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Star}" FontFamily="FA-Solid" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
    <Tab Route="entitys" Title="Entitys">
        <Tab.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Size="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.Book}" FontFamily="FA-Solid" />
        </Tab.Icon>
        <ShellContent Route="entitysCalendar" Title="Calendar" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EntitysCalendarPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="entitysList" Title="List" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:EntitysListPage}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
<ShellContent Route="aboutPage" Title="About" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" >
    <ShellContent.Icon>
        <FontImageSource Size="{StaticResource FlyoutIconSize}" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.InfoCircle}" FontFamily="FA-Solid" />
    </ShellContent.Icon>
</ShellContent>
```

Here is the final result:

[image]

A side not, something in this solution fixed the iOS issue where nothing was selected on initial opening. I'm guessing it was the definded DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Shell.ItemTemplate` to set the background color of the Label and Icon. And use the `VisualStateGroup` to change the color of Selected status.

Shell.ItemTemplate:

```
   <Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*" ColumnSpacing="0" Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Image  x:Name="FlyoutItemIcon"  Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}" HeightRequest="45" />
            <Label x:Name="FlyoutItemLabel"   Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Style:

```
 <Style  x:Key="FloutItemStyle" Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:OnPlatform UWP=Transparent, iOS=White}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemIcon" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemIcon" Property="Image.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I need to control the color of the icon, not the background (the background is correct). I don't see a setting on Image for the color of the image. And I am using a Font Icon, not an image too. Thanks!