# How do I change app shell selected tab colour, MAUI?

Tags: xaml, maui, maui-windows, .net-maui.shell

I am building a windows app using .NET MAUI and I have a flyout shell with some tabs. I would like to change the colour of the selected item, specifically the little blue bar that shows at the left side of a selected item.
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6SIu.png)

I can not find anything that changes this, does anyone know if this is even possible?

Edit:
I have tried the following code and played about with MenuItemTemplate, however I still can not change the colour of the little blue bar on selected items.

```
<Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*">
            <Image Source="home.png"
                   Margin="5"
                   HeightRequest="45"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="test"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   />
            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                   Opacity="50"
                   BackgroundColor="Red"
                   />                
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

This code results in the following:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this select tab can be changed in the maui in windows/App.xaml.

```
 <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"  Color="Red" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="#FF0000" />
  </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

This can change the `SelectionIndicatorForeground` color to red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shell.MenuItemTemplate` to customize the item.

```
  <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.2*,0.8*">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
  </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>

  <Shell.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image" Class="FlyoutItemImageStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background"  
            Value="AliceBlue"></Setter>
        </Style>
  </Shell.Resources>
```

For more information you can refer to [Define MenuItem appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0#define-menuitem-appearance). In addition, I find a sample and you can check this [How to set the Color of Icons in FlyoutItems in AppShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246778/xamarin-forms-how-to-set-the-color-of-icons-in-flyoutitems-in-appshell).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have tried this but I still cannot edit the colour of the little blue bar on the left, do you have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is the windows format, and it can not be changed by using the style. You can change it in the windows11 setting ->Personalize -> Color to change the Windows colors.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is any way to stop MAUI using the windows colours as default and have it use a custom colour so that it can be consistent across users? @Guangyu

Comment: This might belong to the UWP or WinUI3. Due to the maui is based on the winui3.

Comment: @Andrew I find the method to change the select bar color.  Acturally, this is very easy to achieve. I post the new answer you can check it.